# How to Avoid Duplicate Records based on specific keys while inserting Into mysql Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table (TableA) with Those Keys --> **user_id, content_id, points, content_type, description, created_date**

content_id is the unique id of my document, so the every content_id can have 2 records with content_type(1-> like and 2 -> share).

Now I want to avoid duplicate records insertion into **TableA** based on content_id, content_type

**i need Like this:** ( In this table no duplicate records)

```
:id user_id, content_id, points, content_type, description, created_date: 
1    1        1a1           5        1              null     2021-02-26 08:26:54
2    1        1a1           5        2              null     2021-02-26 08:26:56
3    1        1a2           5        1              null     2021-02-26 08:26:54
4    1        1a3           5        2              null     2021-02-26 08:26:56
```

**** I don't need Like this:**** ( In this table have duplicate records (1st & 2nd Id))

```
:id user_id, content_id, points, content_type, description, created_date: 
1    1        1a1           5        1              null     2021-02-26 08:26:54
2    1        1a1           5        1              null     2021-02-26 08:26:56
3    1        1a1           5        2              null     2021-02-26 08:26:56
4    1        1a2           5        1              null     2021-02-26 08:26:54
5    1        1a3           5        2              null     2021-02-26 08:26:56
```

Comment: You don't want `user_id` as part of the unique key?

Comment: no, one user can like all contents but For every content have only one recorded for Like(type-1) and Share (type-2)

Answer (score 0):

Simply make `content_id, content_type` your primary key.  Or, create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the pair.

Comment: If I make content_id, content_type my primary key then For one user can like all contents but For every content have only one recorded for Like(type-1) and Share (type-2). So in this time, content_id is not accepted for another type (either 1 or 2)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the combination of `user_id`, `content_id`, and `content_type` to be unique.
So create a composite `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(
  user_id INTEGER, 
  content_id VARCHAR(10), 
  points  INTEGER, 
  content_type INTEGER, 
  description VARCHAR(100), 
  created_date DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id, content_id, content_type)
)
```

Comment: if I make user_id a Primary Key then, For every user can like multiple contents right and For every content that have content_type=1 and content_type=2, is that scenario will work?

Comment: @Venkatasivaramireddy.Venna I do not propose to make user_id a Primary Key. Read my answer carefully.

Comment: I created Table As you given on above but i did one small change CREATE TABLE TableA(
  user_id INTEGER, 
  content_id VARCHAR(10), 
  points  INTEGER, 
  content_type INTEGER, 
  description VARCHAR(100), 
  created_date DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id, content_id, content_type)
)

Comment: @Venkatasivaramireddy.Venna what change? This is exactly th esame.